# Find an element in a specific row and column in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm having trouble in looking for an element in a specific.

I have the array

```
A = [ 1 2 3 7 2 ; 2 8 5 7 2; 1 9 8 4 1; 8 7 2 10 9; 10 9 4 3 8]
```

I just want to get the index of A(3,4) for the element of 4. However my code spits out the two locations of the element 4, which is A(5,3) and A(3,4).

I used `[row, col] = find(E==4)`

Comment: If you want to know what is in A(3,4), use x=A(3,4), If you want to find number in specific row, use: find(A(SpecificRow,:)==SpecificNumber)

Comment: @beaker I guess it's my fault for making my question vague, sorry. So my objective was to acquire the index of an element adjacent to a starting point. For example, I begin at A(3,3)=8 but I want to move to element 4 adjacent to the starting point, in this instance I want to get the index of A(3,4)=4 and not A(5,3). If that makes any sense. But don't worry I made a general equation already. Sorry for the mix-up :)

Comment: @AiKEA16 Please update your post and title to include all relevant information. Please do not add it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[row, col] = find(E==4, 1)
```

The second parameter is the number of elements you want to find. Find more details at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html

Matlab searches a matrix in column-by-column order. If you want to find the first element by rows, you could transpose E before calling find. But you need to swap the resulting indices then:

```
[col, row] = find(E'==4, 1)
```

Comment: Hi there, this gives me the index of A(5,3), since my code spits out these numbers first. But I want to access A(3,4).

Comment: I changed the answer accordingly

Comment: Sorry this is another follow up. What if I was looking for another element ,for a different array, in a specific row and column, is there a general function/equation that can do this?

Comment: Then you could find the first 2 and use the second. `[cols, rows] = find(A'==4, 2)` and `row = rows(2)`, `col = cols(2)`

Comment: `'` is not transpose. `.'` is

Answer (score -1):

Here's a lengthier, iterative way to find the first index:

```
A = [ 1 2 3 7 2 ;...
    2 8 5 7 2;...
    1 9 8 4 1;...
    8 7 2 10 9;...
    10 9 4 3 8];

[a,b] = size(A);

for i = 1:a
    for j = 1:b
        if A(i,j) == 4
            break
        end
    end
    if A(i,j) == 4
        break
    end
end

index = [i,j]
```

It returned [3, 4] for me.

Comment: Sorry this is another follow up. What if I was looking for another element ,for a different array, in a specific row and column, is there a general function/equation that can do this? For example, I did not want the first index but perhaps the 2nd index,

Comment: If you want to scroll through the index numbers, then all you have to do is do a([insert a number]) and b([insert that same number]) when you use the find() method

Comment: @Harald i know, but that was the quickest method i could immediately think to solve his problem considering he wasn't asking for a general way to do it initially. afaik, if there are 20 elements that are the same in a huge array, then i think the only way, in matlab, to only find the 14th / 20 duplicate element is to iterate.

Comment: @jon_rizk Thank you!